What is the best way to use authentication in conjunction with RateLimit in Ktor?
I wanted to support three types of requests in my application:

Guest access: Requests without an Authorization header.
Custom token access: Requests with an Authorization: Token {token} header. I need to define a custom mechanism to map the token to an AuthUser.
JWT token access: Requests with an Authorization: Bearer {jwt} header.

Each type of request corresponds to a different rate limit:

Guest access: Lowest rate limit.
JWT token access: Higher rate limit.
Custom token access: No rate limit.

What is the best way to implement this setup in Ktor?
I tried using authenticate to protect specific resources, but I encountered an issue with guest access endpoints. Specifically, when a request includes an Authorization header, call.authentication.principal() still returns null.
Alternatively, I could apply authenticate to all requests. However, I'm not sure how to properly implement this approach.
How can I configure authenticate to handle all request types (guest, custom token, JWT) and apply the appropriate rate limits for each case?
authentication {
    jwt {
            authHeader { call ->
                val header = call.request.headers["Authorization"]
                if (header.isNullOrBlank()) {
                    return@authHeader HttpAuthHeader.Single("NoAuth", "")
                }
                if (header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                    return@authHeader HttpAuthHeader.Single("Bearer", header.removePrefix("Bearer "))
                } else {
                    return@authHeader HttpAuthHeader.Single("Token", header.removePrefix("Bot "))
                }
            }
            verifier { header ->
                val scheme = header.authScheme
                return@verifier when (scheme) {
                    "Bearer" -> Jwt.userVerifier
                    "Token" -> TODO("")
                    else -> TODO("")
                }
            }

            validate {
                println(it.payload.toString())
                return@validate AuthUser(role = AuthUser.Role.NoLogin)
            }
            challenge { _, _ ->
                call.respond(DataVo(401, "Unauthorized", null))
            }
        }
    }
}
// reat limit
install(RateLimit) {
    register {
        requestKey { call ->
            val headers = call.request.headers
            headers["X-Real-IP"] ?: headers["X-Forwarded-For"] ?: call.request.origin.remoteHost
        }
        rateLimiter(limit = 6000, refillPeriod = 1.minutes)

        requestWeight { call, _ ->
            val user = call.principal<AuthUser>()
            when {
                // no header Authorization
                user == null || !user.isLogin() -> 20
                // Authorization: Token 
                user.isAdmin() -> 0
                // Authorization: Bearer
                else -> 8
            }
        }
    }
}

